AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape' error
I am trying to predict stock prices. Here is my code:
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as web
import numpy as np

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM

company = 'TSLA'

start='2012-01-01'
end='2024-03-01'

data = web.download(company, start=start, end=end)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data['Close'].values.reshape(-1,1))

prediction_days = 60

x_train = []
y_train = []

for x in range(prediction_days, len(scaled_data)):
    x_train.append(scaled_data[x-prediction_days:x, 0])
    y_train.append(scaled_data[x, 0])

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units = 50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

I excepted it to input out nothing, however I got this error:
but it says as an error,
Traceback (most recent call last):
File
"c:\Users\User1\OneDrive\Documents\Desktop\python\projects\machine\stock_price_predictor.py", 
line 32, in <module>
model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

How to resolve this? I tried converting it into np.array but nothing worked. This was my attempt:
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as web
import numpy as np

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM

company = 'TSLA'

start='2012-01-01'
end='2024-03-01'

data = web.download(company, start=start, end=end)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data=.fit_transform(data['Close'].values.reshape(-1,1))

prediction_days = 60

x_train = np.array([])
y_train = np.array([])

for x in range(prediction_days, len(scaled_data)):
x_train = np.append(x_train, scaled_data[x-prediction_days:x, 0])
y_train = np.append(y_train, scaled_data[x, 0])

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences=True, input_shape= 
(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units = 50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

But instead I got this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File 
"c:\Users\User1\OneDrive\Documents\Desktop\python\projects\machine 
 learning\stock_price_predictor.py", line 32, in <module>
 model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences=True, input_shape= 
(x_train.shape[1], 1)))                                                              
~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: tuple index out of range


"I tried converting into a np.array but nothing worked" - can you please show this attempt so we can try to help you fix it, as that does seem to be the right approach

If you just convert it to a numpy array, e.g., x_train = np.array(x_train), then that array is likely to still just be 1d, so shape[1] (the size of the 2nd dimension) will not exists and x_train.shape[1] will fail. There are several options (depending on what you actually need) 1) just explicitly get the size of the 1st dimension (0-index) with   x_train.shape[0], 2) get the size of the last available dimension with x_train.shape[-1], 3) make x_train 2d with x_train = np.atleast_2d(x_train), 4) use len rather than the shape attribute to get the number of items in x_train.

You are trying to use a numpy arrays attribute for a normal list.
When you write x_train = [] that creates an empty list and data is added to it with the loop. Then with x_train.shape[1] you treat it as numpy array. If you want the length of your list, or how many elements it contains, you can use len(x_train)

x_train is defined as an empty list [].  As stated in the error, lists don't have any attribute called shape.
I'm assuming you're trying to use it as if it were a numpy array.
If you want a more in-depth tutorial on how to use it, see https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_shape.asp
Basically, the shape attribute exists on numpy arrays, not regular python arrays.
You can create numpy arrays with np.array - for example, np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).
